How do I get the model type inside a PydanticBaseSettingsSource?
I'm writing a custom PydanticBaseSettingsSource and processing fields of a specific type MyModel
class CustomSettingsSource(PydanticBaseSettingsSource):
    # Must implement
    def get_field_value(
        self, field: FieldInfo, field_name: str
    ) -> Tuple[Any, str, bool]:
        return ({}, "", False)

    def __call__(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        d: Dict[str, Any] = {}

        for field_name, field in self.settings_cls.model_fields.items():
            # If a field is of type MyModel I do custom processing/fetching
            
            # This returns <class 'mymodule.MyModel'>
            print(field.annotation)

            # This does not work
            if isinstance(field.annotation, MyModel):
                # do stuff...
        return d

I create a config assigning a field the MyModel type:
class Test(MyConfig):
    test: MyModel = MyModel(blah="sdfsdf")

What is the correct way to do this? I really don't want to have do something like if "MyModel" in str(field.annotation): ... because that feels like a hack.

I'm posting as answer, but I'm not sure if it's stable or the "right" Pydantic way to do this. It looks like this returns just the model type as a string:
field.annotation.__qualname__

Why then does:
field.annotation.__class__

Return this:
<class 'pydantic._internal._model_construction.ModelMetaclass'>

But __qualname__ returns the model class name? I haven't used __qualname__ before, is this native python behavior or does Pydantic modify the __qualname__ attribute of its model classes/fields to return this non-standard output?
